# QDialogButtonBox: Is there any way to fill different colors to Individual Buttons?

Tags: qt, qt4, qmessagebox

I am creating an Error Message Box for my Screen. I am using QDialogButtonBox for buttons. 
Now i want to fill Buttons with different colors. 
For example: 
"OK" --> Green
"Cancel" --> Red etc.
I am able to change the background for all buttons , but not individually.

Is there any way to do this ??

Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this(using QDialogButtonBox::button() and QPushButton::setStyleSheet()).

```
QDialogButtonBox* buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox;
// set up your button box
QColor okButtonColor = Qt::red;
buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok)->setStyleSheet(QString("background:%1").arg(okButtonColor.name()));
```

EDITED: typo fixed in code around building style sheet string.

Comment: thanks for ur reply. 
I tried ur way. But it is not giving anything beyond button. In My case:
      ui->buttonBox->addButton(QDialogButtonBox::Ok)
      ui->buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok); // if i try to put (./->) it shows nothing.
Can you please give me more hint. Your idea seems to be good.

Comment: That function return QPushButton * . So, may be you need to include QPushButton. buttonBox->button(QDialogButtonBox::Ok)->setStyleSheet(QString("background:%s").tr(okButtonColor.name())); should work.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late, but I am gonna leave this for a felow developer who went through the same problem as I did, this works for both python and c++ developers, you can use this to change color of a specific button:

```
#<QDialogButtonBox ObjectName> *[text="Save"] {
    background: red;
}
#<QDialogButtonBox ObjectName> *[text="OK"] {
    background: green;
}
```

[Example on Qt Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMGnb.png)